# Troubles installing Tensorflow for R

Tags: r, tensorflow

I'm trying to install TensorFlow for R, and up to now I've followed these steps:

- `devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow"` Worked fine
- `library(tensorflow)`
- `install_tensorflow()`

And at this lasts point I get this error

```
HTTP error 404 while getting https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
Could not install requirement tensorflow==1.9.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl because of error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
Could not install requirement tensorflow==1.9.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl for URL https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Errore: Error 1 occurred installing packages into conda environment r-tensorflow
```

Shortly it seems R tries to install Tensorflow with installing python version `3.7` which is not currently supported by this package (only up to `3.6`).

Is it possible to force `install_tensorflow` to use an earlier python version?

P.S. I saw there is the possibility of using virtual envs, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I think it just comes down to the url being old/invalid. I ended up installing it all manually per [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux)

Comment: @FelipeFlores did you use a virtual env? I've already tried this but something went wrong (not going to discuss this here)

Comment: I tried on a virtual env and the system environment and it was equally painless. Although I think `keras` for R uses the system environment if it's installed. Could be wrong in this

Comment: After having installed TensorFlow globally it worked. I don't know what the problem was but it seems to be solved

Comment: Awesome! Again, I think it's just that google may have changed the format of the url where they store the TF install files and rstudio/tensorflow just doesn't reflect that yet